# .NET Jquery 500 error

Tags: javascript, c#, .net

I recently fixed a scripting error I had for my app, though this used to work and now it doesn't? my other javascript works so its something to do with this function. I just can't see whats wrong with it, in my console window I get this:

> HTTP500: SERVER ERROR - The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.
>   (XHR)GET - http://localhost:57435/Links/ObDo?urllink=http://www.broowaha.com/articles/26890/moving-truck-packing-and-loading-tips

```
$("#Obdomain").on("change", function () {
    var urllink = $('#Obdomain').val();
    var url = "/Links/ObDo?urllink=" + urllink;

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        url: url, // Variabel
        showLoader: true,
        success: changedo // Function
    });
});
```

my controller function:

```
   public JsonResult ObDo(string urllink) {
        string newurl = urllink.Replace("Https://", "").Replace("http://", "").Replace("/*", "");
        var v = new
        {
        domain = db.Identifiers.Where(c => c.domain.Contains(newurl)).First().ID
        };
        String json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(v);
        return Json(json, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: Are you using DI? How the `success` method looks like?

Comment: Looks like a server side error, do you get a message and/or stacktrace?

Comment: @CristianSzpisjak sorry I don't know what DI is :/

Comment: DI = Dependency Injection. Are you using it with ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: You shouldn't do `SerializeObject` if you're passing the result to `Json`; `Json` does the serialization again.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan noted thank you

Comment: @CristianSzpisjak no is it integrated or downloadable?

Comment: @Jerodev 2lines about applicationsinsights.exception and request in my output only, is this useful? Usually my page errors out with a stack trace when its a .net error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1/ Check if

> www.broowaha.com/articles/26890/moving-truck-packing-and-loading-tips

is in your table **Identifiers**

2/ Remove

```
String json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(v);
```

=>

```
public JsonResult ObDo(string urllink)
{
    string newurl = urllink.Replace("Https://", "").Replace("http://", "").Replace("/*", "");
    var v = new
    {
        domain = db.Identifiers.Where(c => c.domain.Contains(newurl)).First().ID
    };
    //String json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(v);
    return Json(v, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

3/ Add

> encodeURIComponent(str)

```
$("#Obdomain").on("change", function () {
var urllink = $('#Obdomain').val();
var url = "/Links/ObDo?urllink=" + encodeURIComponent(urllink);

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    url: url, // Variabel
    showLoader: true,
    success: changedo // Function
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your URL in the fragment needs to be encoded.

If you look at [Uniform Resource Identifier specification (rfc3986)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) The URL you are passing in the fragment (the parameter to your "urllink") needs to be encoded correctly. Look at the [encodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI) function.

Comment: ahh nice, how would I then decode it in the controller action, would this be using HttpUtility.UrlDecode?